Ideas for implementing Cloudflare Turnstile in forms?
My org is having a moderate number of bots register for events in spite of reCaptcha being enabled. I'd like to experiment with Cloudflare Turnstile. Any suggestions for how best to include it in event registration forms, for example?

This would need an extension to be written.  However, if you haven't tried it yet, you may want to try the Form Protection extension, since it uses ReCAPTCHA v3 as well as other bot protection mechanisms.
It also provides a blueprint for implementing alternative CAPTCHAs in extensions if someone wants to tackle the HCaptcha/Turnstile issue.
